# Using CASE with WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to use CASE with WHERE, So if the countryId is -1 do not select any and if else select the value
Here is my nonworking  code

```
 DECLARE @countryId int=-1 --for example
   SELECT * FROM dbo.bbmf WHERE status=1 
 AND countryId =
CASE WHEN @countryId = -1 THEN 
 --select any
ELSE
 countryId=@countryId
END
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you don't want to select any rows if `countryId=-1`, simply don't run the select?

Comment: the select is not alone there is status=1 before the CASE

Comment: If you're not going to return any row, the other where clauses don't matter. Don't run the select at all.

Comment: Is there a countryID = -1 in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like these like this:

```
DECLARE @countryId int=-1 

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.bbmf 
WHERE 
    status=1 
    AND 
    1 = CASE 
        WHEN @countryId = -1 THEN 0
        WHEN countryId=@countryId THEN 1
        ELSE 0 --<<probably don't need the ELSE
    END
```

Comment: I've used this sort of structure a lot in stored procedures used by SSRS reports

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear, so I see two result what you may would like to achive.

**First** is only depending on the `countryID`. So if the `countryID` is -1, do not select any record:

IF you don't have a `countryId` which is -1, then you can use this easy select, because, if the `@countryID = -1`, nothing will return (because of the AND), and if it is not -1, then the needed records will return:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.bbmf 
WHERE status=1 
  AND (countryId=@countryId)
```

(Additional to the first solution, if you have country with id = -1, then you should change the `AND (countryId=@countryId)` To `AND (countryId=@countryId AND @countryId <> -1)` )

**The second** is, that if the `countryId = -1`, then you need only check the status, and get every record with `status = 1`, then you should use this statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.bbmf 
WHERE status=1 
  AND (countryId = -1 
     OR countryId = @countryId)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your performing a `SELECT` statement regardless if Country Id is -1 or not, which is a redundant call.  If you want to just run a SELECT statement if CountryId is not equal to -1 then just filter it out in the `WHERE` clause or use a `Conditional`:

**Filtered:**

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.bbmf 
WHERE status=1 AND countryId != -1
```

**Using a conditional:**

```
IF (@countryId != -1)  
BEGIN
    -- SELECT STATEMENT HERE
END
```

Comment: But where can I put "status=1 AND .."

Comment: @JustMe in your WHERE clause.  This is the place you can apply filters such as status = 1

Comment: Can I use this: Select * from dbo.bbmf where status=1 and IF (@countryId != -1)  
BEGIN
    countryId=@countryId 
END

Comment: @JustMe - that won't work - The SELECT statements needs to go inside the conditional (as my answer suggests).  After BEGIN clause, add the Select * from dbo.bbmf where status=1

Answer (score 1):

Try [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd546/4)

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.bbmf 
WHERE status=1 
AND countryId = @CountryID
AND @countryId <> -1
```

Comment: This is the right one, but it should be `WHERE status = 1 AND (@countryId <> 1 OR countryId = @CountryID)`

Comment: It won't work this way as in [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd546/5). You should write it as I wrote like [this way](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd546/6).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.bbmf 
WHERE status=1 
AND countryId <> -1
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find the use case of your code, but may be you can run a select with a impossible where clause, such as :

> SELECT * FROM dbo.bbmf WHERE status=1 AND 1>2

But, as some say, if you dont want any result, just don't run the query.

Comment: Pretty sure 1 > 2 is going to return false